# dedicated web host

Tags: dedicated-server

I am looking for a decent linux server dedicated with 8GB+ RAM and comparable CPU Spec.  There are too many webhosts out there, any recommendation on a cheap but decent host?
turnkey seems cheap, but is it good?

Comment: This is too subjective. You'd be much better asking a question on how to choose a good webhost bearing in mind what things are important to you.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you're over a gig or two in RAM, it's probably more cost-effective to buy a cheap server and colocate it. [Slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/), for example, is a great host that I highly recommend, but their 8GB servers cost $450/month - and that's pretty inline with what I've seen elsewhere.

Considering reputable companies in my city let you colocate a 1U server in a good datacenter for ~100/month, you'd pay for your server very quickly with the monthly savings.

Comment: Which is great until the first time you need remote hands, or when something breaks and you're down for two days because you can't source spares over a weekend.  Leasing dedicated servers from a company that manages them gets you a lot more than just "the box".

Comment: The savings would likely allow you to have an entire spare *box*, or to pay for same-day maintenance from the server manufacturer. As for remote hands, that's why you get a local colo.

Comment: Also, anyone looking for "cheap but decent" probably isn't running something so mission critical that it can't go down for one weekend in the server's lifespan.